# How to disable TLS 1.0 for Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I've heard it is possible to disable TLS 1.0 and 1.1 with google app engine and custom domain.  How can that be done?

Mike

Answer (score 1):

You now have to [set up a load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless) with an [SSL policy](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-policies-concepts#defining_an_ssl_policy), instead of adding a custom domain in the App Engine settings.

See support discussions [here](https://groups.google.com/g/google-appengine/c/qqp5AlfAHx8/m/UtZFGFwlAwAJ) and [here](https://groups.google.com/g/google-appengine/c/OHyhjlkrDfU/m/UJatEKSPAgAJ).

Answer (score 0):

For this particular request you should create a ticket with the Google Cloud Platform support.

You can create one going to your Google Cloud Console Home -> Main Menu -> Support.

Comment: Is it available for anyone? Seems like you have to pay (Offerings) to disable TLS1.0, TLS1.1...